# How do I put the width or height of an object in to a variable?

Tags: vbscript

I am currently using VBScript in Qlikview and I ran into a problem. My code currently looks like this:

```
sub resize

     set obj = ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject("TX05")
     set fr = obj.GetFrameDef
     set pos = fr.Rect
     set WidthUser = ActiveDocument.Variables("vWidth")

'    set OriginalWidth = pos.Width
'    set OriginalHeight = pos.Height
'    Ratio is 2.5

     pos.Width = Cint(WidthUser.GetContent.String) * 2.5

'    pos.Height = vPreferredWidth/vOriginalWidth * vOriginalHeight

     pos.Height = 200 * 2.5
     obj.SetFrame fr,true,dummy
     msgbox("Changed Width to: " & pos.Width/2.5 & " " & Chr(13) & "Changed Height to: " & pos.Height/2.5)

End sub
```

vWidth is a variable where the user can input his desired width.

So what am I trying to achieve? I want the user to be able to type in his desired width of an object and then press a button called "resize". When the button is pressed, the object width should change to the desired width and the object height should also change in relation to the change in width.

For example, we start with an object that has a Width of 120 and a height of 200. The user then puts in his desired Width of 60 and then presses the button "resize". The object width should change to 60 and the object height should change to 100 (60/120*200=100). So in the end result the ratio width/height is still the same (120/200 vs 60/100).

The problem I am having is trying to capture the original width and height of my object. I tried using:

```
set OriginalWidth = pos.Width
set OriginalHeight = pos.Height
```

But that doesn't work at all. I tried all kinds of variations but nothing worked so far. What I don't understand is that when I type:

```
msgbox(pos.Width)
```

I do get a result, but when I use:

```
set OriginalWidth = pos.Width
msgbox(OriginalWidth)
```

I get nothing at all (I get thrown back into my script).

Can anyone help me figure this out? Would also love some feedback on the rest of the code, because I just started learning this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT after help I changed my code to:

```
sub resize 
'   Ratio is 2.5
    set obj = ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject("TX05")
    set fr = obj.GetFrameDef
    set pos = fr.Rect
    set WidthUser = ActiveDocument.Variables("vWidth")
    set HeightUser = ActiveDocument.Variables("vHeight")

    OriginalWidth = pos.Width
    OriginalHeight = pos.Height
    DesiredUserWidth = Cint(WidthUser.GetContent.String)

    pos.Width = DesiredUserWidth * 2.5
    pos.Height = DesiredUserWidth / OriginalWidth * OriginalHeight * 2.5
    obj.SetFrame fr,true,dummy
    msgbox("Changed Width to: " & pos.Width/2.5 & " " & Chr(13) & "Changed Height to: " & pos.Height/2.5)
End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [docs for Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44(v=vs.84).aspx) and from now on use it only when you assign an object to a variable.

```
    set OriginalWidth = pos.Width
==>
    OriginalWidth = pos.Width
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are the rest of my "set"'s correct or are there more mistakes? I don't really understand why set WidthUser = ActiveDocument.Variables("vWidth") is correct, but not set OriginalWidth = pos.width? Besides the docs for set, where can I learn more about the differences and when to use what? I am really new to this, so I see that you are right, but I don't quite understand why yet.

Comment: I added my new code to my original post. I was wondering if I can change "Cint(WidthUser.GetContent.String)" to something smaller, because If i understand correctly I am first turning it into a String and then a Int. Can't I just immediately make it an Int?